# Intermittent NoMethodError RoR application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm stumped on this one.

I get :

```
NoMethodError in Customers#edit

Showing /opt/www/vhosts/barhi/app/views/customers/edit.html.erb where line #73 raised:

undefined method `start_date' for #<Job:0x9fea5ac>
```

Intermittently.

If I go back to index.html.erb and **shift+reload** and then click the customer, it works and *works for every other customer* as well!

Flow:

customers/index.html.erb

I see a list of customers.  Some have jobs, some don't - **this bug only appears when the customer does not have any jobs**.

I click a customer with no job - it flows into this method in customers_controller:

```
def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if params[:job_id]
       @selectedJob = Job.find_by_id(params[:job_id].to_s)
    else
       @selectedJob = Job.new
    end
    @jobs = Job.find_by_customer_id(params[:id].to_s)
  end
```

Enlarged NoMethodError complains about undefined method start_date:

```
<%if @selectedJob.start_date %><% start_date = DateTime.parse(@selectedJob.start_date) %><% start_date = start_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')%><%else%><% start_date = @selectedJob.start_date%><%end%>
```

So you would say "well @selectedJob isn't being set" - but it is, I've tested with logger.debug statements in the controller and @selectedJob.new works fine:

```
def new
  @job = Job.new
end
```

I tried @job -> @selectedJob saved and tested and no change, so it's not the instance variable name (which I didn't really think it was to begin with, but sometimes I'm just dumb)

The kicker is that when I hit the back button, shift+reload the page, then click the customer with no job - it works fine.

Developer Tools console shows:

```
edit
/customers/51b78a4e97279123fd000255
GET
500
Internal Server Error
text/html
```

Before the shift+reload, then after:

```
edit
/customers/51b78a4e97279123fd000255
GET
200
OK
text/html
Other
jquery-ui.css
code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness
GET
200
OK
text/css
edit:10
Parser
(from cache)

jquery-1.9.1.js
code.jquery.com
GET
200
OK
application/x-javascript
edit:11
Parser
(from cache)

jquery-ui.js
code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2
GET
200
OK
application/x-javascript
edit:11
Parser
```

Truncated because there are a lot of things the page loads - but the most important question, why does edit.html.erb *sometimes* fail to load?

Reproduce by logging out of the application, shift+reload to clear cache, log in, go to customers page, click customer without job, it fails, back button, shift+reload, click, it works.

There has to be some kind of step in some controller or something that is failing to call the edit page properly after the login (like some exclude statement on a previous page?) but then when you're on the index page loads fine.

I'm going nuts.

Comment: It would help if you could disable your cache and see how it behaves without all of this shift-reloading.

Comment: @Zach - Did as you suggested, disabled cache, and the system works the exact same.  login, click customers, click on customer with no jobs, error, click back, reload (not shift+reload but no caching anyway) click again, error, do this twice more just for fun, click back and this time shift+reload, and then click and it works.  No behavioral change.

Comment: Did you add anything beyond the default options to your Gemfile? What version of Rails? And I see you're using hashes instead of ids - are you on ActiveRecord, or are you using something like Mongoid?

Comment: Where does the start_date get set when creating a new Job? In the Job model? It seems to me that when selecting edit for a customer with no jobs the flow would go here: else / @selectedJob = Job.new / end  , but I don't see a save anywhere, perhaps this is done somewhere else or I have missed it. Perhaps hitting back actions a save somewhere so it doesn't error out again.

Comment: @Zach Using MongoMapper, Rails 3.2.13, honestly don't recall what the default in the Gemfile was - but I know these are pretty custom:

gem 'json'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'comma', '~> 3.0'
gem "mongoid-paperclip"
#gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'iconv'

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case I don't think I figured out why the error was happening, but I fixed the error by just seeding in start_date and end_date values on job.new like:

Job.new({start_date => Date.today, end_date => Date.today}) so the page loads with those fields pre-populated with today's date.  Problem never appeared after that, so I'm calling it a solution of sorts.